# Starting from Android11, do I need to comply to Android's SAF just to even create a file at public Download location?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11, storage-access-framework

I am on Android 11. I just want to be able to create a file in `/storage/emulated/0/Download` directory on my phone. So, this is the public Download folder that I need to create a file on.

I don't need access to read/modify/delete other files in `/storage/emulated/0/Download`. i just want my app to be able to create and replace a file of its own at `/storage/emulated/0/Download`. Thats it!

**Question:**

- Do I need to go by the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) for this?
- Do I need any special permission for this?
- Or is it possible get access to `/storage/emulated/0/Documents` without going through the hassle of Android SAF?

My app is able to create a file at `/storage/emulated/0/Download` using Android 10 but it fails to do that since Android 11.

My use case is very simple. I just want to create a file at `/storage/emulated/0/Download` and keep appending more data to the file by replacing it with a new one from time to time.

Running the following code on Android 11 fails for me:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(path, "Somefile.txt");
String location = file.getAbsolutePath();

try {
     file.createNewFile();
     byte[] data1 = {1,1,0,0};
     OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
     fo.write(data1);
     fo.close();
     Log.i(TAG, "The file is created at " + location);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e(TAG, "Exception creating file");
     return location;
 }
```

Comment: You do, file API is only functional within scope of your apps private directory or when you use the dangerous permission to manage all files.

Comment: Okay. Then I need to go through SAF. Is there a simple example of how to create a file in `/storage/emulated/0/Download` for example using SAF? There are all these too complicated examples floating around. All I need to do is to just create a file at `/storage/emulated/0/Download`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to go by the Storage Access Framework for this?

No.

> Do I need any special permission for this?

No, though you will need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for older devices.

> Or is it possible get access to /storage/emulated/0/Documents without going through the hassle of Android SAF?

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` [is being undeprecated](https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/11/06/about-environment-undeprecations.html), so it is safe to use that to access `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`. That should give you the same [access that you have with `MediaStore`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/11/scoped-storage-stories-diabolical-details-downloads.html):

- You can create files there
- You can read and write your own files<sup>1</sup> there
- You have no access to other apps' files there

<sup>1</sup> For the purposes of this bullet, "your own" refers to your current app installation — if the user uninstalls and reinstalls your app, files from the old installation of your app are no longer considered to be "your own".

So, for example, this activity works just fine without any permissions in a `targetSdkVersion 31` project:

```java
package com.commonsware.downloadtest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    writeToDownloads();
  }

  private void writeToDownloads() {
    try {
      File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
      File target = new File(dir, "test.txt");
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(target));

      out.println("hello, world!");
      out.flush();
      out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("DownloadTest", "Exception writing to Downloads/", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, this code *sucks*, in that it does not handle older devices, does the I/O on the main application thread, etc. However, it writes data to the designated file, on a Samsung A50 running Android 11.

Note that this will give an exception if the file already exists. So, for example, I thought that this example did not work, until I realized that I already had `test.txt` in `Downloads/` from some experiment that I did a month ago. Once I deleted that file, the sample worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for this. So, as I understand you, I should be able to call `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` and create a file there *without* going through Android's Storage Access Framework(SAF). Correct?

Comment: Your answer applies to Android 11. Right? Please note that I am not bothered about Android 12 as of now. I just need my app to be able to work on Android 11

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer: "Correct?" -- correct. At worst, you can use `MediaStore`, but using the filesystem APIs should work as well. "Your answer applies to Android 11. Right?" -- correct. "Please note that I am not bothered about Android 12 as of now" -- other than Android 12L formally undeprecating those APIs, I do not think anything changed in this area in 12/12L.

Comment: undeprecated? they just can't make up their own minds can they

Comment: Trying to create a file at `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` fails for me on Android 11. I updated the question with the code snippet I tried. Let me try the MediaStore API to see if that works. I have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission declared in my Manifest file so that I am able to work on devices below Android 10. I hope that permission is not working against me on Android 11. And please note that I dont have `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` declared in my Manifest file.

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer: "I updated the question with the code snippet I tried" -- what is the exception that you get? And, are you sure that `Somefile.txt` is not already there? "I have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission declared in my Manifest file so that I am able to work on devices below Android 10" -- note that you also need to request it at runtime. "And please note that I dont have android:requestLegacyExternalStorage declared in my Manifest file" -- that might be needed for Android 10, but otherwise it should have no effect.

Comment: I have declared `requestLegacyExternalStorage`. `file.createNewFile()` is not able to create the file. I have runtime requested for the the permissions and grant it on the app start.

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer: What is the exception that you get? And, are you sure that `Somefile.txt` is not already there?

Comment: I am sure that `Somefile.txt` does not exist. But I expect it to exist after call to `file.createNewFile()`. It doesn't. So, this is where the problem starts. Trying to write into a file that does not exist will of course throw an exception

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer: "Trying to write into a file that does not exist will of course throw an exception" -- that has not been the case since the introduction of Java, 20+ years ago. `createNewFile()` is not necessary.

Comment: Can you just add an example code of a file creation at `/storage/emulated/0/Download` and writing some dummy data to it? Thanks for following up til here. I already accept the answer. One small request to give a code sample if possible in Java.

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer: Um, there isn't really much to it -- see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding that sample code :+1